# Android context menu custom positioning?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, contextmenu

I have managed to do this for Toasts and Dialog boxes, but now the trouble of context menu has arisen. Is it possible in Android to position a context menu to a different location programmatically? I want to be able to specify the position anywhere on the screen as part of a custom user interface, but I cannot seem to figure out how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK you can't.  You could create your own dialog that looks like a context menu and position that instead.

Comment: Rather than a Dialog I think I can use a PopupWindow and position it based on the finger's location. I'll give it a try later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in my comment, I went with a [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) for the actual menu view. It contained a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) for the menu items with appropriate event listeners. I attached the context menu by overriding the long press listener and adding the [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) at [`event.getRawY()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getRawY%28%29).

Comment: To see a demo of what I did check out XDA (https://market.android.com/details?id=com.tombarrasso.android.wp7uidemo). It is part of my Windows Phone 7 User Interface implementation in Android OS version 1.6+. I also put a donate demo version in the market (https://market.android.com/details?id=com.tombarrasso.android.wp7uidemo).